# add index migration adding column instead of migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I am trying to add a index to a column which already exists in my table by.

I want to add a index on item_id on product_images table

```
bundle exec rails generate migration AddIndexToProductImages item_id:integer:index
```

but the code i see in the migration file is

```
class AddIndexToProductImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :product_images, :item_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Not sure what could be causing this, can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails will not autogenerate the migration with content just for index

Edit the generated migration with following:

```
class AddIndexToProductImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :product_images, :item_id
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks deepak, have accepeted your answer but is there any official documentation that says so or link where i can read more about "Rails will not autogenerate the migration with content just for index"

Answer (score 1):

Following is the command to generate index migration File:

```
bundle exec rails generate migration AddIndexesToProductImages item_id:integer:index
```

In case it does not have proper command to add index, you can edit the generated file with the appropriate index you want to add. You will have to wring following in the `change` function.

```
def change
  add_index :product_images, :item_id
end
```